# Content inside IFRAME not showing when targeted from html FORM (only in Internet Explorer)

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, iframe, target

**THE PROBLEM**

I am attempting to create an AJAX style photo upload by directing the action (a php page) of a html form to a target (an iframe).
The below example works flawlessly in Google Chrome & Firefox, however in Internet Explorer (im using IE 8) the php echo doesn't display in the html iframe. The iframe remains empty.

**THE HTML**

```
`<iframe name=myTarget>< /iframe>  
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=upload.php target=myTarget >  
<input type=file name=filename />  
<input type=submit />  
</form>`
```

**THE PHP**

```
`<?php  
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $filename);  
echo $iframe_html = "   
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<link href=css/style.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css media=screen charset=utf-8 />  
</head>  
<body>  
<img id=set_uploaded_photo class=set_uploaded_photo src=$filename />  
</body>  
</html>";
?>`
```

**OTHER NOTES**

- By placing a src=otherpage.php as an attribute of the iframe, successfully shows the content inside the iframe (in all browsers including IE).
- I use the doctype < !DOCTYPE html> in the parent html document & the iframe document.